# Extract the last word from a string using C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

My string is like this:

```
string input = "STRIP, HR 3/16 X 1 1/2 X 1 5/8 + API";
```

Here actually I want to extract the last word, 'API', and return.

What would be the C# code to do the above extraction?

Comment: Is "STRIP" a word, or is the first word "STRIP," ?

Comment: What's your pattern? Last 3 letters? last thing appeared after +? last thing appear after last operator?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Well, the naive implementation to that would be to simply split on each space and take the last element.

Splitting is done using an instance method on the [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) object, and the last of the elements can either be retrieved using array indexing, or using the [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) LINQ operator.

End result:

```
string lastWord = input.Split(' ').Last();
```

If you don't have LINQ, I would do it in two operations:

```
string[] parts = input.Split(' ');
string lastWord = parts[parts.Length - 1];
```

While this would work for this string, it might not work for a slightly different string, so either you'll have to figure out how to change the code accordingly, or post all the rules.

```
string input = ".... ,API";
```

Here, the comma would be part of the "word".

Also, if the first method of obtaining the word is correct, that is, everything after the last space, and your string adheres to the following rules:

- Will always contain at least one space
- Does not end with one or more spaces (in case of this you can trim it)

Then you can use this code that will allocate fewer objects on the heap for GC to worry about later:

```
string lastWord = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

However, if you need to consider commas, semicolons, and whatnot, the first method using splitting is the best; there are fewer things to keep track of.

Comment: The `Substring(input.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1)` is surely best choice for performance, why would anyone on earth split an entire string to get the last word???
And BTW, **you're wrong** about missing chars; the substring will return last index of ' ' or last index of entire string, which means same result. Check it out yourself: http://rextester.com/IFEGJ69776

Comment: @Shimmy `.LastIndexOf` doesn't return "last index of entire string" (which would actually be `0`) if it cannot find the string match, it returns `-1` which of course then becomes `0` when adding `1` which happens to give you the whole string in this instance.

Comment: Check this link, I'm testing an empty string and it gives the same result. [Check it out](http://rextester.com/CXJYN16822).

Answer (score 16):

First:

```
using System.Linq; // System.Core.dll
```

then

```
string last = input.Split(' ').LastOrDefault();

// or

string last = input.Trim().Split(' ').LastOrDefault();

// or

string last = input.Trim().Split(' ').LastOrDefault().Trim();
```

Comment: what if after the last word if it is having some space like "STRIP, HR 3/16 X 1 1/2 X 1 5/8 + API       ";

Comment: I am unable to use Last(), it is saying system.array does not contain definition for Last. My class is implementing an interface, i think that is the reason i cannot use last(), so please tell me how to use it

Comment: Last() is an extension (LINQ) method, you need .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: @Pradeep: Use the namespace System.Linq

Comment: If i try to use System.Linq in my class file it is saying namespace name Linq does not exists in namespace system.

Comment: @Pradeep: Verify that System.Core assembly is present in the project references.

Comment: I think I cannot use Linq because, i am using vs 2008 IDE and my application runs on .net framework 2.0. Please tell me is there any alternatives to this.

Comment: can't we use Linq in class library

Comment: If you do not want to use Linq, then you need to modify @Taz's code a bit as suggested by @Lasse V. Karlsen

Answer (score 9):

`var last = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(' ')).TrimStart();`

This method doesn't allocate an entire array of strings as the others do.

Comment: Do you need to +1 to LastIndexOf()? Or have I done my answer wrong? :)

Comment: @El Ronnoco Yeah, You do, but your answer will fail if the string ends in a space. (index beyond end of string = exception). TrimStart is safer. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
string workingInput = input.Trim();
string last = workingInput.Substring(workingInput.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim();
```

Although this may fail if you have no spaces in the string. I think splitting is unnecessarily intensive just for one word :)

Answer (score 3):

```
static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly char[] DefaultDelimeters = new char[]{' ', '.'};

    public string LastWord(this string StringValue)
    {
        return LastWord(StringValue, DefaultDelimeters);
    }

    public string LastWord(this string StringValue, char[] Delimeters)
    {
        int index = StringValue.LastIndexOfAny(Delimeters);

        if(index>-1)
            return StringValue.Substring(index);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

class Application
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        string sentence = "STRIP, HR 3/16 X 1 1/2 X 1 5/8 + API";
        string lastWord = sentence.LastWord();
    }
}
```

Comment: Default behavior should be to return StringValue is index == -1. Also, you should return StringValue.Substring(index + 1).

Answer (score 2):

```
var lastWord = input.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "STRIP, HR 3/16 X 1 1/2 X 1 5/8 + API";
var a = input.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(a[a.Length-1]);
```