# Displaying the last word in a sentence in uppercase

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'am tring to display the last word in the sentence in uppercase but It will only select the last one or the uppercase.

This is my code:

```
 string sentence = "write LINQ queries to do the following";
 string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
 IEnumerable<string> query =
        from w in words
        select w.Last()
        .ToUpper;
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the last word from the sentence in uppercase, using linq?

Comment: that's exactly  what I mean

Comment: What would be the expected output for the example sentence string you provided? What would you want the output to be if the last word ("following") started with a capital F?

Comment: NO. The expected  output should be "FOLLOWING".

Comment: So you don't want "LINQ"?, your current code should already return "FOLLOWING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using linq:

```
var res = sentence.Split(' ').Last().ToUpper();
```

Or a little more efficent:

```
var res = sentence.Substring(sentence.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1).ToUpper()
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to do a `Join` to return the list back to a sentence string?

Comment: @Ulric from the op's comment on the question the expected output should be "FOLLOWING".

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to filter all the words which are in UPPERCASE and get the last word like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> getLastWord(string str)
{           
    var upper =  str.Split(' ')
                .Where(s => String.Equals(s, s.ToUpper(),
                            StringComparison.Ordinal)).Reverse().Take(1);

    return upper;

}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Nu0dqI)**

Comment: How can I do it with a query ?

Comment: @sara:- This is using the LINQ approach. What else do you want?

Comment: She wants to use the query expression like in her example and not the fluent (dot) notation like you do. They are both LINQ though, I prefer the dot notation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.  Seems like they just want to grab the last word and then upper case it.  No need to do any filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it like this: [Extract the last word from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603911/extract-the-last-word-from-a-string-using-c-sharp) and add ToUpper at the end? Simple one liner.

Answer (score 0):

without linq, it will be more efficient

```
 string res = sentence.Substring(0, sentence.LastIndexOf(' ')+1) + 
sentence.Substring(sentence.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1).ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last word, in upper case form, the very simplest way to do that is using the LINQ methods, which under the hood is the same as the LINQ query approach:

```
var upperText = sentence.Split(' ').Last().ToUpper();
```

This assumes that the split works correctly and there aren't any empty entries at the end, so you may need to add:

```
var upperText = sentence.Split(' ').Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).Last().ToUpper();
```

And that will work, and functions the same way as the attempt you made above.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ is inefficiently here. You can just find last word and make it upper.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string sentence = "write LINQ queries to do the following";
         int nLastWord = sentence.LastIndexOf(' ');
         string strLastWord = sentence.Substring(nLastWord + 1,
            sentence.Length - nLastWord - 1).ToUpper();

         Console.WriteLine(strLastWord);
    }
}
```

Simulation [link](http://ideone.com/EaMkFq).