# Capture Characters after special Char with Regex

Tags: regex

I have strings that are built like this

```
"Colour: Black
Size: L"

"Colour: Black
Size: XS"
```

All I want to capture are the characters after Size: but with no whitespace, I have  come up with the following

```
(?<=\Size:)[^\]]+
```

Comment: So what's your question? Is it not working the way you expect? What results are you getting?

Comment: Im getting space after Size: so im looking to get rid of the white space also.

Comment: Negative look behind is really not required here. You can do make little change in your own regex and make it this (?<=\Size: )[^\]]+ introduced a space after Size: but quantifying whitespace in a negative look behind can't be done, so better you can use the regex in my answer which covers variety of cases.

Comment: After updating your post, are those doublequotes included in the string or they are just enclosing the string?

Comment: Double quotes are included yes, and i run into an issue as using this in .net c# where cant end with ") like (?<=Size: ).*?(?=")

Comment: You may use `Regex.Match(s, @"\bSize:\s*([^""]+)").Groups[1].Value` (if the right boundary is a `"`). No need of lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewtrying this now, thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution worked perfectly, i cant mark as an answer though

Comment: Also, if you just need to return substrings after last space, [it is even easier without a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603911/extract-the-last-word-from-a-string-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Thank you! very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the post got updated, updating the needed regex too.

```
Size:\s+([^"]+?)"
```

Explanation:

- Size:\s+ --> This matches Size: literally followed by one or more whitespace characters
- ([^"]+?) --> Captures the string you are interested in
- " --> Expects doublequote at the end of input to stop capturing the intended data

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/hxi7dJ/3

Here is a C# sample codes for the regex,

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        string s = "\"Colour: Black Size: XS\"";
        string sizeVal = Regex.Match(s, @"Size:\s+([^""]+?)""").Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine("sizeVal: " + sizeVal);
    }
```

This gives following output,

```
sizeVal: XS
```

Notice how I have escaped doublequote with an additional doublequote in the regex. You may check it with any values of your input strings.

Comment: I think there is already a reputation penalty for downvoting answers.

Comment: Are you referring to -1 self one? For not leaving a reason or leaving a wrong/stupid reason, penalty should be higher.

Comment: @SimonR - You can't downvote. You need a rep of 125 to do that.

Comment: I see the main trouble you had was escaping a doublequote. I didn't knew you were using c# language else would have given a sample code too. Try tagging your post with a language too, so answerers can help you better. If you try using my regex, that will work too. Just make sure you escape a doublequote with actually two doublequotes.

Comment: @SimonR: I've add sample C# code using my regex too, which also gives you the output you expected. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ive accepted your answer, Yes sorry should have stated that this was C# and put in the tag also.

You are correct, it was the double quotes which were really throwing me off.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I have a slightly more complex string that has cropped up but cant get around it.

String is (needs to be able to still capture the original string) "Colour: Black<br />Size: L<br />Length: Regular"

Ive tried this \bSize:|Length:|Regular\s*([^""]+) but it only gets Length and Size now, can you point to me where im going wrong please?

Comment: @SimonR: Yes that's right, you made it... But as I can see the string you are interested to capture contains only alphabets so you can use this character set[a-zA-Z] or even use a word character \w and your simplified regex becomes this Size:\s*(\w+) which will capture what you wanted initially. \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] Check here https://regex101.com/r/hxi7dJ/6

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thanks mate, very helpful!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi For the record, suggestions to penalize downvotes are not deemed reasonable, and suggestions of the kind are usually shot down. You might wish to read more about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1233251

Answer (score 2):

Try Regex: `(?<=Size: ).*?(?=")`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1X4krl/1)

Comment: Works great also, Thanks.

Comment: This won't work in case there are multiple spaces after "Size:" (as that way the intended match will also contain spaces which OP doesn't want) which is why I discouraged lookarounds for solving this. See this https://regex101.com/r/1X4krl/2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of your full requirements but depending on where you are getting at, I think the following regex will work.

```
/(?<=Size:\s)(\w+)(?=\")/g
```

> 1. **Positive Lookbehind** `(?<=Size:\s)`: Assert that the Regex below matches. `Size:` matches the characters Size: literally (case
>      sensitive). `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to
>      `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
> 2. **1st Capturing Group** `(\w+)`: `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited
>      times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> 3. **Positive Lookahead** `(?=\")`: Assert that the Regex below matches. `\"` matches the character `"` literally (case sensitive)
> 4. **Global pattern flags**: `g`(global) modifier matches all (don't return after first match)